# How to plot vector field of a function with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, plot

How can I draw a vector field of a function with tikz?

For example f(x,y) = 4x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> - 5

[image: What I want to plot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! This post could be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461693/draw-a-vector-field-using-psvectorfield

Comment: It helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `pgfplots` you can draw a vector field with the option `quiver`. This option creates a 3d vector field, but you can choose to view it 'from above' adding the `view={0}{90}` to the `axis` options.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
  view     = {0}{90}, % for a view 'from above'
  domain   = -3:3,
  y domain = -3:3,
  xtick    = {-3,...,3},
  ytick    = {-3,...,3},
]
\addplot3[blue, quiver={u=8*x, v=2*y, scale arrows=0.05}, samples=16, -latex] (x,y,0);
\addplot3[red, thick, domain=0:360, samples=41] ({0.5*sqrt(5)*cos(x)},{sqrt(5)*sin(x)},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Juan Castano: I think the red one is the ellipse `4x^2 + y^2 =5` where the speed (velocity) of solutions of the ODE `y' = 4x^2 + y^2  - 5` is vanishing. It seems to contradict with your figure. Am I wrong something?

Comment: @BlackMild, Well, the original post asked for the representation of a vector field but gave the equation of a scalar field. What I did was to assume (I don't know if correctly) that what was needed was to represent the gradient. And the ellipse, in that case, would be a level set. It looks quite similar to the original drawing, but it may be wrong.

Comment: @JuanCastaño Yeap! I think there is some incorrect information from OP